# jetty:run causes class not found exception for org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext

Tags: jetty, classnotfoundexception, maven-jetty-plugin

Hi i have the following configuration.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.3.v20120416</version>
</plugin>
```

and in my jetty-env.xml I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
</Configure>
```

When i run with mvn jetty:run i get the following error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppCont
ext
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:92)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.nodeClas
s(XmlConfiguration.java:349)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configur
e(XmlConfiguration.java:314)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.jav
a:279)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.applyJettyXml(AbstractJett
yMojo.java:449)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMo
jo.java:467)
```

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 21):

I suspect you have a jetty-web.xml or some old jetty configuration files floating around

`org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext` = `org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext`

the packaging is different in jetty7 and 8 since we moved to the eclipse foundation a few years ago.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Starting/Porting_to_Jetty_7

Comment: Thanks but now I get this exception 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object of class 'org.mortbay.jett
y.plugin.JettyServer' is not of type 'org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext'.

Comment: assuming that space in 'jett y' above is an error in just your comment, what file are you processing here? is it a jetty-web.xml in your WEB-INF directory, an old context.xml file or something else?

Comment: their is no jetty-web.xml just plain web.xml like fro tomcat.

Comment: Hi found the problem. I change to

    <Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server"> 

and things work